# Screenshot in google map android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Is it possible to take a screenshot of the google map programmatically in android that is currently outside of my screen/viewing window.

Comment: Look at this answer, and I hope you serve...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android

Answer (score 0):

It is sadly not capable of doing that right now. But you can hard code it. there is a read the location method (and you can add distance or radius d to that to find other locaitons and record them)on google maps api